# Dynamically convert property to Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Is it possible to simplify this logic, Is there generic way to do it.
The code finds marked attributes and parses it according to the attribute type.
Please suggest some way to optimize this code, all the data type of Product class will be string, I'm getting product input as xml directly converting serialized data to a class with decimal,int,float will not give proper error message, If there is list of item it throws error in xml we wont know which row has caused the error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSolution
{
    public interface ICustomParser
    {
        bool Parse(string input);
    }

    public class DecimalParserAttribute : Attribute, ICustomParser
    {
        public bool Parse(string input)
        {
            if (input == null) return false;

            decimal decimalValue;

            return decimal.TryParse(input, out decimalValue);
        }
    }

    public class intParserAttribute : Attribute, ICustomParser
    {
        public bool Parse(string input)
        {
            if (input == null) return false;

            int intValue;

            return int.TryParse(input, out intValue);
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        [DecimalParser]
        public string Weight { get; set; }

        [intParser]
        public string NoOfItems { get; set; }

        [intParser]
        public string GRodes { get; set; }

        [intParser]
        public string WRodes { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var sb = Validate(new Product() { NoOfItems = "1", GRodes = "4", Weight = "5", WRodes = "23" });

            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            sb = Validate(new Product() { NoOfItems = "1", GRodes = "4w", Weight = "5", WRodes = "23" });

            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string Validate(Product product)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var property in product.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var value = Convert.ToString(property.GetValue(product, null));

                var sel = property.GetAttribute<ICustomParser>();

                if (sel == null) continue;

                var parserinstance = (ICustomParser)Activator.CreateInstance(sel.GetType());

                if (parserinstance.Parse(value)) continue;

                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} Has invalid value", property.Name));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T GetAttribute<T>(this PropertyInfo property)
        {
            return (T)property.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(s => s is T).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be better suited at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: i like your method, i dont know this approch ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one type (`Product`), it probably isn't worth it - just write the validation code explicitly without all the fancy stuff. If, however, you have multiple types to inspect (perhaps known only at runtime):

---

It really depends how fast it needs to be. How often does this run? If it is periodic, then there isn't a vast amount to do - the main change would be to *just cast the parser directly*:

```
var parserInstance = (ICustomParser)sel;
```

(it already *is* the attribute type)

If it is critical path, then there is a *lot* you can do to beef it up, but you get into the realm of metaprogramming - which is essentially what most tools like serializers and ORMs do to reduce runtime reflection. If you're not familiar with hacking IL at runtime, I would recommend looking at a tool like "Sigil" (available on nuget) that makes it hard to get wrong (or at least: tells you *what* you've done wrong). Essentially, you can inspect the data structure and then *emit* the IL that matches what it would look like if you were doing it all in explicit code; for example, emitting IL that looks kinda like:

```
static readonly DecimalParserAttribute _decimal = new DecimalParserAttribute();
public static void Validate(Product product) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(!_decimal.Parse(product.Weight)) {
       sb.Append(...);
    }
    // ... etc
    ...,
}
```